# Using a string as part of an #each loop in handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

Relatively new to `handlebars.js`, but not templating. I am using two loops to output markup in specific order. Both `collections.intro` and `collections.elements` are created by https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith-collections.

**Javascript**

```
var order = ['intro', 'elements'];

collections.intro = [
 { title: 'One' },
 { title: 'Two' }
];

collections.elements = [
 { title: 'One' },
 { title: 'Two' }
];
```

**Handlebars**

```
{{#each order}}

  {{this}} /* intro, elements */

  {{#each ../collections.[this]}}
    {{this.title}}
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

Is there anyway to use `this` from the `order` loop to access the correct `collections`. Both `collections[intro]` and `collections[elements]` work when hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve this with a custom helper:

**Javascript**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( 'collection', function ( slug, options ) {
  return options.data.root.collections[slug];
});
```

**Handlebars**

```
{{#each order}}

  {{#each (collection this)}}
    {{this.title}}
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```